# sending DataStream from VM socket to Kafka and receiving on Host OS's Flink program : Deserialization Issue

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

I am sending data stream from VM to Kafka's test topic (running on host OS at 192.168.0.12 IP ) using code below

```
public class WriteToKafka {

    public  static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        // Use ingestion time => TimeCharacteristic == EventTime + IngestionTimeExtractor
        env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.IngestionTime);

        DataStream<JoinedStreamEvent> joinedStreamEventDataStream = env
                .addSource(new JoinedStreamGenerator()).assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new IngestionTimeExtractor<>());

        Properties properties = new Properties();

        properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "192.168.0.12:9092");
        properties.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", "192.168.0.12:2181");
        properties.setProperty("group.id", "test");

        DataStreamSource<JoinedStreamEvent> stream = env.addSource(new JoinedStreamGenerator());
        stream.addSink(new FlinkKafkaProducer09<JoinedStreamEvent>("test", new TypeInformationSerializationSchema<>(stream.getType(),env.getConfig()), properties));

        env.execute();
    }
```

`JoinedStreamEvent` is of type `DataSream<Tuple3<Integer,Integer,Integer>>` it basically joins 2 streams `respirationRateStream` and  `heartRateStream`

```
 public JoinedStreamEvent(Integer patient_id, Integer heartRate, Integer respirationRate) {
        Patient_id = patient_id;
        HeartRate = heartRate;
        RespirationRate = respirationRate;
```

There is another Flink program that is running on Host OS trying to read the data Stream from kafka . I am using localhost here as kafka and zookeper are running on Host OS.

```
public class ReadFromKafka {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // create execution environment
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        properties.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2181");
        properties.setProperty("group.id", "test");



       DataStream<String> message = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer09<String>("test", new SimpleStringSchema(), properties));

       /* DataStream<JoinedStreamEvent> message = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer09<JoinedStreamEvent>("test",
                new , properties));*/

        message.print();


        env.execute();


    } //main
} //ReadFromKafka
```

I am getting output something like this

[image]

I think I need to implement deserializer of type `JoinedStreamEvent`. Can someone please give me an idea how should I write, the deserializer for `JoinedStreamEvent` of type `DataSream<Tuple3<Integer, Integer, Integer>>`

Please let me know if something else needs to be done.

P.S. - I thought of writing following deserializer, but I don't think it is right

```
DataStream<JoinedStreamEvent> message = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer09<JoinedStreamEvent>("test",
                new TypeInformationSerializationSchema<JoinedStreamEvent>() , properties));
```

Comment: `TypeInformationSerializationSchema` should also do the job but you need to pass the `TypeInformation` to the constructor: `TypeInformation.of(JoinedStreamEvent.class)`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to receive events VM in the same format by writing a custom serializer and deserializer for both VM and host OS program as mentioned below

```
public class JoinSchema implements DeserializationSchema<JoinedStreamEvent> , SerializationSchema<JoinedStreamEvent> {


    @Override
    public JoinedStreamEvent deserialize(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
        return JoinedStreamEvent.fromstring(new String(bytes));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEndOfStream(JoinedStreamEvent joinedStreamEvent) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public TypeInformation<JoinedStreamEvent> getProducedType() {
        return TypeExtractor.getForClass(JoinedStreamEvent.class);
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] serialize(JoinedStreamEvent joinedStreamEvent) {
        return joinedStreamEvent.toString().getBytes();
    }
} //JoinSchema
```

Please note that you may have to write fromstring( ) method in your event-type method, as I have added below fromString( ) JoinedStreamEvent Class

```
public static JoinedStreamEvent fromstring(String line){

        String[] token = line.split(",");

        JoinedStreamEvent joinedStreamEvent = new JoinedStreamEvent();


        Integer val1 = Integer.valueOf(token[0]);
        Integer val2 = Integer.valueOf(token[1]);
        Integer val3 = Integer.valueOf(token[2]);

        return  new JoinedStreamEvent(val1,val2,val3);


    } //fromstring
```

Events were sent from VM using below code

```
stream.addSink(new FlinkKafkaProducer09<JoinedStreamEvent>("test", new JoinSchema(), properties));
```

Events were received using following code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // create execution environment
    StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
    properties.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2181");
    properties.setProperty("group.id", "test");


    DataStream<JoinedStreamEvent> message = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer09<JoinedStreamEvent>("test",
            new JoinSchema(), properties));

    message.print();



    env.execute();


} //main
```